# Linear-Algebra - How to find a position vector of a point S on a plane, that is also perpendicular to the plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

I want to find the coordinates of a position vector of a point S on a plane. This position vector must be perpendicular to the plane. I don't really have an idea on how to approach this.
The general form of the equation of the plane W is: `x - 2y + z = -2`. 
The answer must be in this form:

(s<sub>x</sub>, s<sub>y</sub>, s<sub>z</sub>) with s<sub>x</sub>, s<sub>y</sub> and s<sub>z</sub> as the `x`, `y` and `z` coordinates of the vector `s` 
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The plane

$$x-2y+z=-2$$

has normal vector $$\vec n=(1,-2,1)$$

thus the position vector we are looking for is in the form

$$(s_x,s_y,s_z)=a(1,-2,1)$$

by the condition to belong to the plane we obtain

$$a-2(-2a)+a=-2\iff6a=-2\iff a=-\frac13$$

therefore

$$(s_x,s_y,s_z)=\left(-\frac13,\frac23,-\frac13\right)$$